# Ethernet LAN Port broken on HP Compaq 6730s. What model is compatible to mine?

Tags: laptop, ethernet

My little brother broke the Ethernet LAN port on HP Compaq 6730s. I wanted to order this part, but I can't anywhere find the part for this model. I found this on E-bay:

[HP Compaq 6720S - Ethernet LAN Port & Cable](http://www.ebay.com/itm/331127579208?euid=0037d2d42fa84d938c4142e8d761cc3d&bu=43772689732&cp=1&sojTags=bu=bu)

I asked the owner, can I use this on HP Compaq 6730s, but unfortunately he doesn't know. Does anyone know can I order this and replace it in my laptop?

Comment: If you are unsure, another solution is to buy a USB to Ethernet adapter.

Comment: does that make any difference in quality of the connection?

Comment: No, it is just a passthrough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken 2 of those apart a couple of years ago.
(One was coffee-soaked, the other had a cracked display. Salvaged the display from the coffee-victim and used that to the repair the other one.)

I clearly remember that both had the LAN port soldered unto the motherboard.
It is not replaceable unless you are willing to replace the entire motherboard which is not something (if you can find the parts) an inexperienced DIY person should attempt to do.
(I'm assuming you are not experienced, because you had to ask this question...)

This is a quite old laptop. It doesn't make much sense to spend a lot of time and effort on a repair.
You're best option seems to be to get a USB-ethernet adapter and use that instead. You can find those online as cheap as $15.

Comment: does that make any difference in quality of the connection?

Comment: @DR_ You won't notice the difference. USB2.0 (you laptop doesn't have 3.0)  has a theoretical throughput of 480 Mb/s and ethernet is just 100 mb/s.  In theory USB ethernet has slightly worse latency, but that only comes in effect in high-performance online gaming, which your laptop can't handle anyway.

Comment: Cool... Thanks. No, I just need a better connection, since the wifi signal is not that strong in my room.